# Logic error in calculations tree using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make calculations tree using js to get the total of the items which is categorized under parents and sub-parents as so on.

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

This is my HTML structure and js code which I need to edit.
I will be grateful for any solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sum = 0;

    $('ol.dd-list').each(function(){
        sum = 0;
        $(this).find("ol > li span").each(function(i, obj){
            if($(this).text() !== ""){
                sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
                $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.price').text(sum);
            }
        });
        sum = 0;
        
    });

    

});
```

```html
<div class="card-content">
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li class="item">Main 1 <span class="price"> | 240,000 EGP</span></li>
    <ol class="dd-list">
      <li class="item">Sub 1.1<span class="price"> | 130,000 EGP</span></li>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li>Sub 1.3<a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a><span class="price"> | 130,000 EGP</span></li>
        <ol class="dd-list">
          <li><a class="item">New Item 3</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 60,000 EGP</span></li>
          <li><a class="item">New Item 4</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 70,000 EGP</span></li>
        </ol>
      </ol>
      <li>Sub 1.2<a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a><span class="price"> | 110,000 EGP</span></li>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li><a class="item">New Item 3</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 50000 EGP</span></li>
        <li><a class="item">New Item 4</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 60000 EGP</span></li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </ol>
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li>Main 2 <a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
    <ol class="dd-list"></ol>
  </ol>
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li>Main 3 <a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
    <ol class="dd-list"></ol>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all include jquery library, Hope this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sum = 0;
  
    var CountTotal = function(element) {
      if($(element).children('ol.dd-list').length > 0) {
        $(element).children('ol.dd-list').each(function(){
          CountTotal(this)
        })
      }else{
        var temp;
        $(element).find('.price').each(function(){
          if(temp = $(this).text().replace(' | ', '').replace(',', '').split(" ")[0]) {
            sum += parseFloat(temp)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  
    CountTotal($('.card-content > ol.dd-list'))
    console.log("Total Sum: ", sum)
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-content">
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li class="item">Main 1 <span class="price"> | 240,000 EGP</span></li>
    <ol class="dd-list">
      <li class="item">Sub 1.1<span class="price"> | 130,000 EGP</span></li>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li>Sub 1.3<a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a><span class="price"> | 130,000 EGP</span></li>
        <ol class="dd-list">
          <li><a class="item">New Item 3</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 60,000 EGP</span></li>
          <li><a class="item">New Item 4</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 70,000 EGP</span></li>
        </ol>
      </ol>
      <li>Sub 1.2<a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a><span class="price"> | 110,000 EGP</span></li>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li><a class="item">New Item 3</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 50000 EGP</span></li>
        <li><a class="item">New Item 4</a><span class="pull-right price"> | 60000 EGP</span></li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </ol>
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li>Main 2 <a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
    <ol class="dd-list"></ol>
  </ol>
  <ol class="dd-list" type="1">
    <li>Main 3 <a class="btn btn-primary shadow btn-xs sharp ml-1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
    <ol class="dd-list"></ol>
  </ol>
</div>
```